# Reviewing Chess Tactics Puzzles

Tags: tactics, training, puzzles

Is there somewhere online I can play chess tactic puzzles and redo them whenever I want? I do tactics on lichess but it doesn't store my puzzles. Is there somewhere that stores all my tactic problems so I can redo them? I feel that would be better to develop pattern recognition. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure why you would want to redo a specific puzzle This would rather train you to remember that particular solution which is not what you want (because it is not general enough). BTW, if you fail a puzzle in lichess  you will be asked to re-do it in increasing intervals as you can read about here: https://en.lichess.org/blog/WDY6cCEAALYi5Xg2/puzzles-update

Comment: Both Dan Heisman and Michael de la Maza recommend this approach. Improving pattern recognition means that you're more likely to see the tactic in games, and more importantly to see if your opponent would have a tactic in response to a move you're considering.

Comment: @LarryColeman I don't question that you should improve pattern recognition. However I don't see the advantage of loading manually a specific problem which you solved before over having the computer automatically present me problems (both new and those that I failed before).

Comment: Apart from not seeing the point, I also see a practical problem: How are you going to find a puzzle among the hundreds or thousands of puzzles you did?

Comment: You wouldn't go back and find a puzzle manually. You would use spaced repetition and have the software repeat the puzzles for you on a schedule. The software would show you problems you had problems with more often, and problems you always got correct less often. I thought your response was questioning redoing problems in general. I apologize if I misread it.

Comment: @LarryColeman Seems like we agree then. I should have emphasized "specific" in my comment. Spaced repetition is what lichess does automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a premium membership on ChessTempo, you can create problem sets with spaced repetition, which is one of the advanced options under problem search. If you select this option, the site will show you both new puzzles and puzzles you've already solved. You'll see puzzles you've gotten wrong more often, and if you get a puzzle right a few times, you won't see it as much.

Lucas Chess, which is a desktop program and free to download, also includes sets of tactics puzzles for training using spaced repetition.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a specific tactics site that stores all your previous puzzles so that you can redo them.  However, to develop pattern recognition you don't need to do the exact same puzzles over again - doing different puzzles with the same type of tactic / concept is just as good or better.

It's better to get a variety of examples for one tactic / concept, since it would cover more of the possibilities you can face in a game.  Just doing a few puzzles many times wouldn't be as good, since it doesn't cover enough of the types of positions you may run into during a game.

If you want to see full solutions immediately after you get a puzzle wrong, try Chess Tempo.  It shows you the full solution after you finish and let's you play through it.

Answer (score 0):

I do problems on Lichess, and they do save at least the last 15 that you've done.  There are little boxes for each of these in sequence under the current problem diagram that you can click on to bring up the old problem diagrams.  The boxes are either green or red according to whether you have solved or failed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As Larry Coleman Said, a premium membership on ChessTempo will allow you to do that. I would like to add that Lichess also implemented this feature in 2016. Without you knowing it, it repeats problems that you got wrong until you get them right. [See this blog post](https://lichess.org/blog/WDY6cCEAALYi5Xg2/puzzles-update?ref=WECl9SQAABW7y_74~WECl9SQAAODcy_72)

Answer (score 0):

Our site https://xakemate.eus offers this option when registered

Comment: Welcome to [chess.se]! Thanks for disclosing your affiliation, that is [required](/help/promotion) on Stack Exchange.